# Comando "npm" não funcionando corretamente no Windows 8.1 Single Language x64

Tags: node.js, npm

Estou executando o comando **npm** no **CMD** mas não está tendo retorno, nem quando peço para exibir a versão do **npm**, já dei total permissão na pasta do **nodejs**, já fiz um simples teste com o **nodejs**, como o Hello World!, já criei um servidor simples e tudo show de bola com o nodejs, mas quando tento utilizar o npm o "bixo pega", já cheguei a passar uma tarde aguardando para ver se aparecia algo, mas nada. Vou colocar umas imagens para vocês observarem como é o comportamento.
*Fica desta forma para tudo!*
[image: npm -v]

No comando `npm -v` pelo menos aparece depois de tentar cancelar. Já nos outros como `npm install` nada acontece ou com `npm init`
[image: Ctrl + C]

Comment: Dá uma olhada no seu path. Veja as configurações [nessse link](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows)

Comment: Blz @josivan vou dar uma lida e tentar a solução... vlw

Comment: Não funcionou @josivan

Comment: Tente `npm install -g npm/npm`.

Comment: Nada deu certo @josivan

Comment: não sei mais o que tentar. Talvez o problema seja no windows. Tente executar outros scripts e veja o resultado. Talvez o node está funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Já tentou rodar os comandos pelo Git Bash ao invés do CMD? Achei fácil p/ configurar o path. (botão direito no programa > "Propriedades" e preencher "Iniciar em:" c/ seu diretório de projetos. Eu tive um problema com HD cheio e ele salvou minha vida. Boa sorte! https://git-for-windows.github.io/

Comment: Os comandos com node estão funcionando de boa! Acredito que seja um problema no meu Windows mesmo vou tentar uma varredura geral através de algo que esteja dando esse erro, mas vlw @josivan.

Comment: @romulobastos blz vou tentar, assim que tiver o resultado posto aqui

Comment: @M.Cardoso, não deixe de compartilhar se encontrar a solução.

Comment: @josivan ok, não esquecerei... Obrigado!

Comment: OK, estou de volta com a solução, muito simples que até entristece. Vamos aos passos:
Executar os passos deste post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)
Depois executei um programa de limpeza e analisei os registros no **regedit** para excluir as chaves antigas, executei a instalação novamente dei permissão à pasta do nodejs e reiniciei a máquina e funcionou.
Agradeço a ajuda de todos!

Comment: @M.Cardoso poste a solução como a resposta por favor para ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PASSOS

- [Remova completamente o NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)
- Execute um programa de limpeza (eu utilizei o CCleaner)
- Analise os registros no **regedit** (muito cuidado para não apagar o que não deve, faça um backup dos registros antes)
- Instale novamente o NodeJS e dê permissão à pasta do NodeJS
- Reinicie o computador.

*Desfrute do NodeJS e boa sorte*